# Почему запрос выводит только одного ученика вместо всех

Tags: sql

Здраствуйте составил маленький запрос что бы он выводил всех учеников сдавших экзамен на 4 и 5, но он выводит только одного

```
SELECT a.[SURNAME], b.[SUBJ_ID],b.MARK
FROM Студенты a
join [Экзаменационные оценки] b on a.[STUDENT_ID]=b.[STUDENT_ID]
where b.MARK=4 or b.MARK=5
Order by b.MARK desc, a.[SURNAME] asc`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должно выводить вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сколько записей выдаст запрос select * from [Экзаменационные оценки] where mark=4 or mark=5?

Comment: 99% за то, что проблема в исходных данных. Покажите вывод в случае, если закомментировать либо удалить всё предложение WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Запрос рабочий, проверь данные в таблицах.

---

Вместо этого:

```
where b.MARK=4 or b.MARK=5
```

лучше писать так:

```
WHERE b.MARK IN (4, 5)
```

Comment: Чем вторая запись лучше первой?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов удобочитаемостью(короче и проще запись для глаза) и безопасностью(если потом допишешь условие AND, то не нужно думать на счёт скобок/приоритетов). В целом, если для чего-то есть конструкция, то лучше использовать именно её, с точки зрения семантики

Comment: Ну это на ответ не тянет, только на комментарий

Comment: @CrazyElf какой вопрос - такой ответ) Если автор дополнит вопрос сведениями о таблицах, то я либо удалю, либо дополню свой ответ, а если нет - то пусть пользуется своим скриптом без опасения, сообщество одобряет)

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin Про качество вопроса я и не спорю, но это не повод опускаться в ответах на тот же уровень ))  Ладно, я, наверное, придираюсь